# Allowing classes with different parents to extend class without multiple inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

My application has the following class:

`MyTextField`, which extends `JTextField`.

I, however, need the methods inside `MyTextField` in the following class:

`MyPasswordField`, which extends `JPasswordField`.

Multiple inheritance isn't allowed in Java, and I'd like to avoid to copy-paste 85% of the class because of this. How to overcome this *"limitation*"?

Comment: Regarding why I'd want to do this; both fields are going to use the same "system" for placeholders, which both `JXXXField` classes lack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a helper class that defines the shared functionality. Declare a field in each of `MyTextField` and in `MyPasswordField` to hold an instance of the helper class. Relay calls to the helper as needed for the shared functionality, which then only needs to be coded once.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Composition instead of Inheritance.
Your MyPasswordField class can contain an instance variable to myTextField, then you can just use the method using your instance and it's methods.
Let me know if I am going on the wrong track and you expect something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of a Helper class with static methods, so you don't need keep an instance of the helper class in your testfields classes.